# Why is my SoundPool mute?

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I setup my `SoundPool`, and load a sound resource as this in `onCreate()`:

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.edible_underwear, 1);
```

And then I try to play this sound twice in a `onClick()`, one slow mostly in left speaker, and one fast mostly in the right speaker:

```
soundPool.play(soundId, 0.9f, 0.1f, 0, -1, 0.7f);
soundPool.play(soundId, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0, -1, 1.5f);
```

No sound can be heard. I have fiddled with the volumes, priorities and rates. So far to no avail. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What are you playing it with? Perhaps you need an instance of MediaPlayer e.g. MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

Comment: R.raw.edible_underwear .... interesting

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out that `SoundPool` have two bugs/restrictions.

1. The sound volume is from 0.0f to but not inclusive 1.0f. Both 1.0f and 0.0f are mute, so you must cap your volume at 0.99f.
2. Loading samples into the `SoundPool` that do not fit in ram will not result in an exception being thrown, nor is there a `soundId` returned that can be checked for failure. So you must look at your logs, and pray to the Android gods that your samples fit on the target device.

Comment: I suspect your first point is the problem I am having! Glad someone figured it out. Why would the API use 0.0 _and_ 1.0 as mute?!!

Comment: Because if you step back and look at Android as whole, then Android is an inconsistent mess. It is quite obvious that each developer follow their own standards of design, and if it compiles+works, then it is good enough.

Comment: We loose precious development time with errors like this! I can't believe that this was causing me so many errors with sound. Thanks PeyloW for providing this information!