# Recording over existing audio file in android

Tags: java, android, audio

I am currently building an app in android, and I am trying to record my audio over an existing audio file (without changing the length of the file), does anyone know how is it possible to do that? Everything I tried just puts the audio files one after another in one file.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you use to record an audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. You should use GGmpeg for Android, for example. Here you have some questions like yours.

- [question with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808214/9415337)
- [more detailed tutorial](http://dmitrydzz-hobby.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-build-ffmpeg-and-use-it-in.html)
- [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/javacv/KsyqJTYarYE/4jJaDRUXmqMJ)
- [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820282/9415337)

B. Another approach, although limited, is Android SoundPool. Check documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html).

> The sound pool requires you to manage multiple files rather than doing
>   mixdowns and playback of a single file. It would be cool if the
>   soundpool let you grap the output as a IOStream but, alas, the SDK
>   doesn't seem to allow it. Further, it would be nice if the
>   AudioRecorder allowed you to grab a stream from the music layer...but
>   that doesn't look possible either. List of audio inputs:
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html

SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2254086/9415337

C. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2254086/9415337) suggest also doing it in a backend server.

D. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12799238/9415337) might also help you.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help! Yet I still have a problem because I use windows, and he this is a download of a tar file.